# PyKCS11 get token certificates

Tags: python, openssl, ssl-certificate, pkcs#11

I am using PyKCS11 library to read read the certificates from a token device.

This is the code I am using right now, the problem is that the attributes are binary.

```
pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
pkcs11.load("C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll")
slot = pkcs11.getSlotList()[2]
session = pkcs11.openSession(slot, PyKCS11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION)
objects = session.findObjects([(PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS, PyKCS11.CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
all_attributes = [PyKCS11.CKA_SUBJECT, PyKCS11.CKA_VALUE, PyKCS11.CKA_ISSUER, PyKCS11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY, PyKCS11.CKA_END_DATE]

for object in objects:
    try:
        attributes = session.getAttributeValue(object, all_attributes)
    except PyKCS11.PyKCS11Error as e:
        continue

    attrDict = dict(list(zip(all_attributes, attributes)))

    if attrDict[PyKCS11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY] == (0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0):
        continue

    print attrDict[PyKCS11.CKA_SUBJECT]
    print attrDict[PyKCS11.CKA_VALUE]

session.closeSession()
```

What it prints is a tuple, something like: (48L, 130L, 5L, 192L, 48L, 130L, 4L, 168L).

How can I extract the subject name and the x509 certificate ?4

***EDIT***

I managed to solve it in the end. Just in case someone else is struggling this is the way to to get the certificate:

```
    pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
    pkcs11.load("C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll")
    slot = pkcs11.getSlotList()[2]
    session = pkcs11.openSession(slot, PyKCS11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION)
    objects = session.findObjects([(PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS, PyKCS11.CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
    all_attributes = [PyKCS11.CKA_SUBJECT, PyKCS11.CKA_VALUE, PyKCS11.CKA_ISSUER, PyKCS11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY, PyKCS11.CKA_END_DATE]

    for object in objects:
        try:
            attributes = session.getAttributeValue(object, all_attributes)
        except PyKCS11.PyKCS11Error as e:
            continue

        attrDict = dict(list(zip(all_attributes, attributes)))

        if attrDict[PyKCS11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY] == (0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0):
            continue

        x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1,
                                                   str(bytearray(attrDict[PyKCS11.CKA_VALUE])))

    session.closeSession()
```

Comment: Hi I am trying you method, but in the end I get this error
[('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_CHECK_TLEN', 'wrong tag'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I', 'nested asn1 error')]
What should  I do ?

Comment: Are you sure the certificate is ok on the token ? This error usually means the certificate is not ok stored: it has spaces, or is in a different format

Comment: @lukaskiss, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yop, I used Openssl library. You can see it in the Edit section.